# Celery: Why might the 'result' attribute be missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I have put in a line of code, like this:

```
some_var = celery.result.AsyncResult(id)
```

*celery* in this example is an instance of the class Celery imported from the celery module, and this is what happens in the console:

```
AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'result'
```

An additional note, if I change *celery* in the above line of code to not be an instance of the Celery class, but rather, this:

```
import celery
```

the celery module itself, then this error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncResult` is a class inside `celery.result` module.

There is no `result` attribute on `Celery` application object.

It's ok to call `Celery` instance `celery` as long as you initialise it after the imports from `celery` package.

```
# here "celery" refers to the celery package
from celery.result import AsyncResult 

# ... doesn't matter what "celery" points to here ...

result = AsyncResult("task-id")
```